# Inside RecyclerView.Adapter scroll to position

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have to scroll to position X after register a click Listener inside of RecyclerView.Adapter class!!

```
    class MyAdapter(context: Context, mRV: RecyclerView, mLayoutm: LinearLayoutManager) {
    ...

         override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
              holder.itemView.XY_button.setOnClickListener { // Button inside a cell  

                    mRV.layoutManager.scrollToPosition(x)  // Not work
                    mRV.scrollToPosition(x)      // Not work
                    mLayoutm.scrollToPosition(x) // Not work
                    (context as MyRVClass).mRV.mLayoutm.scrollToPosition(x) // Not work
                    (context as MyRVClass).mRV.scrollToPosition(x) // Not work
                    // it does't work with smoothScrollToPosition() too
              }    
         }
    }
```

PS: I solved this problem in swift/iOS with the delegate protocol, 
do we have something equivalent in android/ Kotlin?

Comment: scrollToPosition() and smoothScrollToPosition() should work.  Try doing it outside of the adapter though.

Comment: Outside of adapter is working, but i have to scroll after clicking on a button what was inside of my cell/ adapter.

Comment: What is `MyRVClass` that you cast the context?

Comment: is my AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create this method in your activity's class where the `RecyclerView` is:

```
fun scrollToPosition(position: Int) {
    rv.scrollToPosition(position)
}
```

replace `rv` with the `RecyclerView`'s id

and inside the listener add this:

```
val myActivity: MainActivity = context as MainActivity
myActivity.scrollToPosition(x)
```

replace `MainActivity` with the activity's name and `x` with the position to be scrolled to.

Comment: @A.Amini it's not strange. The activity is the place to perform the scrolling, so you call the activity's method to do the job.

Comment: the question was on how to scroll RecyclerView from the adapter and not how to use a public function of an activity =/

Comment: This seems like an anti-pattern. The adapter should probably not know anything about the RecyclerView or Activity.

Answer (score 5):

A bit late to the party, but I did it like this (also `RecyclerView.Adapter`)

```
class MyAdapter(...){
    private lateinit var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView
    }

    fun scrollToPosition(position: Int){
        mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(position)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVVM architecture you can maybe implement something that looks like this:

1. In the ViewModel have a field to store the position to scroll to as LiveData.
2. In the Activity/Fragment that holds the RecyclerView, observe that field and scroll to its position when it changes.